# WordPress custom a page of posts now showing up

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using this code from [the tutorial](http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates#A_Page_of_Posts) on WordPress official site but all it shows me is my header and my footer and nothing in between. I think it should show me the posts on my blog.

What must be wrong? Please guide me. Thanks.

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Page Of Posts
*/

/* This example is for a child theme of Twenty Thirteen: 
*  You'll need to adapt it the HTML structure of your own theme.
*/

get_header(); ?>

    <div id="primary" class="content-area">
        <div id="content" class="site-content" role="main">
        <?php 
        /* The loop: the_post retrieves the content
         * of the new Page you created to list the posts,
         * e.g., an intro describing the posts shown listed on this Page..
         */
        if ( have_posts() ) :
            while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

              // Display content of page
              get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); 
              wp_reset_postdata();

            endwhile;
        endif;

        $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

        $args = array(
            // Change these category SLUGS to suit your use.
            'category_name' => 'music, videos', 
            'paged' => $paged
        );

        $list_of_posts = new WP_Query( $args );
        ?>
        <?php if ( $list_of_posts->have_posts() ) : ?>
            <?php /* The loop */ ?>
            <?php while ( $list_of_posts->have_posts() ) : $list_of_posts->the_post(); ?>
                <?php // Display content of posts ?>
                <?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); ?>
            <?php endwhile; ?>

            <?php twentythirteen_paging_nav(); ?>

        <?php else : ?>
            <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'none' ); ?>
        <?php endif; ?>

        </div><!-- #content -->
    </div><!-- #primary -->

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: are you using twentythirteen theme?

Comment: @RamSharma: I am using a premium built theme.

Comment: I feel, you may need to create child theme for your premium built theme

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. All I need to do is to go to my theme and find the blog.php related file that displays blog posts. Put them in a newly created file template.